# Can't log out of Woocommerce when I redirect wp-login to home

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, woocommerce

Since all users including admin can log in through the my-account page of Woocommerce, I was thinking that redirecting wp-login.php to homepage would be a good idea for an extra layer of security. so I put the following code in .htaccess:

```
Redirect /wp-login.php http://127.0.0.1
```

but when I click on the logout link of Woocommerce, it redirects everyone to homepage instead of logging out:

```
127.0.0.1/?action=logout&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fmy-account%2F&_wpnonce=fea51efff4
```

Is there any chance to block wp-login.php and only use my-account page for logging in and out?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comments adding this solution now, where in condition I am looking that query string to `wp-login.php` shouldn't have `logout` action to redirect it to login page.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !action=logout
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-login\.php/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}
```

Comment: Oh I realized right now that when you block access to `/wp-login.php` you actually block it for `/wp-login` as well. so basically the answer is yes but like I said it would cause issues when you're logging out of Woocommerce!

Comment: @Timito, if its `wp-login.php` should be forbidden then try edited ones. Is it request directly going to `wp-login.php` or its having some other link or query string? If you could share some sample links here would be great too.

Comment: sorry I forgot to tell you that the modified code didn't work at all. unfortunately I'm working on it in a local server. there's no external link

Comment: @Timitom, The link which you shared it helped. Could you please check my EDIT solution once and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: Thank you so much RavinderSingh. you're amazing! first it would throw the `The page isn’t redirecting properly` error but then I realized that the code has to be right below `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` in .htaccess

Comment: @Timitom, just small correction(for safer side), change from `^/wp-login.php/?$` TO `^/wp-login\.php/?$` to make `.` as literal character, cheers.

Comment: Oh I missed this one. I updated the code and everything is working just fine. can't thank you enough Ravinder